# Как получить кол-во элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Допустим, есть матрица

```
int** matrix = new int*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[columns];
}
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 15;
    }
}
```

и есть функция

```
void func(int**& matrix){}
```

Можно ли получить количество строк и столбцов матрицы, чтобы не передавать их постоянно в параметры функции?

Comment: нельзя, поэтому используйте std::vector

Comment: Нужно передавать параметры, их можно передать в а) аргументах б)структуре в)параметрами шаблона template

Answer (score 4):

В C и C++ такие возможности не предусмотрены, т.к. "голые" массивы хранятся просто в виде последовательностей ячеек в памяти без какого-либо признака окончания.

Последуйте авторитетному [мнению Бьерна Страуструпа и других гуру C++](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rsl-arrays) – используйте `std:array` для последовательностей неизменяемой длины и `std:vector` для последовательностей, длина которых может динамически меняться в ходе работы программы. Эти контейнеры поддерживают метод подсчёта длины, а также множество других удобных и безопасных функций.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое понятие, как структура. Это данные как либо связанные между собой.

```
typedef
struct {
int * * row ;
size_t width ;
size_t height ;
} Matr ;
```

Её и передавайте.

```
void func(Matr & matrix){ .. }
```

Comment: А почему `typedef struct`? Вопрос же не по С

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Для обратной совместимости. **Когда** программер будет убегать от плюсов, будет проще. ;)

Comment: Тогда и ссылку удаляйте